# Import error in the file im working on throwing no module found

Tags: python

I have attached the file structure , and I'm using this code to import modules, but its throwing no module found error, though I have used correct code to import the module

```
from helper import get_summary , spicy_rander , fetch_news , fetch_news_links
```

I have also attached my file structure

[image]

Just tried importing but caught up with no module found error

Comment: Please prefer text to images wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are details you have omitted, but here's the LIKELY cause.  When looking for modules, Python does not look in the folder containing the script.  It looks in the "working directory".  For example, If you run this as `python src/first/app.py`, then the "working directory" is the one containing `src`, and `helper` will not be found.  You can do

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from helper import ...
```

to add the script's directory to the path.